# Change a Div class with JQuery dependant on date

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

New to JQuery and I can't for the life of me figure this out.  I know it's going to be a simple one.

Can't do this server side.

I am working on a site for a client about Seasonal Yoga.  On the getting started page I have 5 divs for each of the seasons.  I only want one to appear dependent on what the date is in any given year.

For example Spring is March 1st to May 31st inclusive.

Summer follows on from that etc etc.  I have not been given the specific dates as yet.

Using Foundation 5 so I attached .hide to each div.

So the script should check the date and remove the .hide class from whichever of the divs is the correct season.

```
<div id="winter-panel" class="hide small-12 medium-6 columns">
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>Winter</h3>
    <p>Winter is the water element, a time to flow smoothly and be reflective in our thoughts and in our actions.</p> 
    <p>Natures energy is at it's lowest at 1/5 and the earth seems quieter as vegetation has gone and animals are hibernating - 
            we should do the same: slow down, sleep when you can and conserve energy for the lighter months ahead.</p> 
    <a class="button" href="winter.html">Read more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By getting the current month of the year you can hide or show your divs..

```
    $( document ).ready( function() {
      var now = new Date();
      var currentMonth = now.getMonth();//returns 0-11
      //based on month hide or show your div
      if( currentMonth > 0 && currentMonth < 5 ) {
      $( "#winter-panel").show();
      } 
      else {
      $( "#winter-panel" ).hide();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Winter would then contain the following numbers: 11 , 0 and 1.
In your code you are checking from Januari to May.

Answer (score 0):

As chinmayahd pointed out you could use the `.getMonth()` Method from the DateObject. In the code I have posted I added a fiddle for you to look at. What I basically did was creating a "range" of month's checking on the current month. I do not necessarily like how I use the cancel variable and I'am pretty sure there is a "cleaner" way of limiting the range but it works.

```
//html
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">3</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none;">4</div>

//javascript
var date2 = 3
var date3 = 6
var date4 = 9

var today = new Date();
var cancel = false;

if(today.getMonth()<date2) {
  $('#div1').show();
  cancel = true;
}

if(today.getMonth()<date3 && !cancel) {
  $('#div2').show();
  cancel = true;
}

if(today.getMonth()<date4 && !cancel) {
  $('#div3').show();
  cancel = true;
}

if(today.getMonth()>=date4 && !cancel) {
  $('#div4').show();
  cancle = true;
}
```

**[Fiddle with curent Month](http://jsfiddle.net/jPa9p/29/)**

**[Fiddle without curent Month for testing](http://jsfiddle.net/jPa9p/33/)**